# Usando o DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gente, como faço uma condição com o DATEDIFF apaga os dados de uma tabela em 12 em 12 meses?

Exemplo:

Você está em junho de 2020 - Então ele apaga tudo o que seja anterior a 01/06/2019.

Outro exemplo:

Você está em dezembro de 2021 - Então ele apaga tudo o que seja anterior a 01/12/2020.

Estava testando só para ver o que acontece, mas não deu certo..:

Select * from rvr_tb where ano_mes / 100 <  dateadd(yyyy, +1, getdate())

Mas acaba lendo o 202104, por exemplo, mas quero que apareça somente os que tenha na coluna 202004. Não posso definir isso, pois esse dado muda.

Comment: E o que significa `ano_mes / 100`? Qual o tipo de dado de `ano_mes`? Se você deseja 1 ano atrás não deveria utilizar `dateadd(yyyy, -1, getdate())`?

Comment: @anonimo então, uma coisa que achei errado e está dificultando minha condição para excluir os dados do ano anterior, a coluna ano_mes está como int.Sabemos que se for 202004 é igual a 04/2020, mas se eu vou utilizar esse campo em funções tipo data, já não dá mt certo. Não estou sabendo converter tbm e não sei o que posso fazer.

Comment: Experimente utilizar a função `DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )` para criar um campo do tipo date a partir de 3 inteiros. Ou crie um inteiro como `(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())`.

Comment: @anonimo mas não tem a parte 'dia' é só ano e mês

Comment: Se quiser trabalhar com o tipo de dado date use, por exemplo, 01 para o dia.

Comment: @anonimo não dá certo utilizar DATEFROMPARTS

Comment: `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2020, 06, 01);` dá como resultado `2020-06-01`.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender e aproveitar melhor o site vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente

```
-- código #1 v2
declare @UmAno int;
set @UmAno= cast (convert (char(6), dateadd (year, -1, current_timestamp), 112) as int);

DELETE 
  from rvr_tb 
  where ano_mes < @UmAno;
```

A vantagem do código acima é que ele é *[sargable](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)*, o que possibilita ótimo desempenho caso exista índice pela coluna ano_mes.

Sobre apagar conjunto de linhas sugiro a leitura do artigo [Apagar conjunto de linhas em tabelas enormes](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/delete-vlt/), onde estão descritos cuidados ao apagar linhas sem interferir com os demais processos.

---

Eis o cálculo de @UmAno, passo a passo:

```
-- código #2 v2
SELECT dateadd (year, -1, current_timestamp),
       convert (char(6), dateadd (year, -1, current_timestamp), 112),
       cast (convert (char(6), dateadd (year, -1, current_timestamp), 112) as int);
```

Observe que há uma última conversão para o tipo de dados *integer*, de modo a evitar que na cláusula WHERE ocorra conversão automática de tipo de dados. Dependendo do contexto a conversão automática de tipo de dados pode gerar resultados errados ou demora no processamento. Detalhes no artigo [Os perigos da conversão automática de tipos de dados](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/).